# How to configure Unity with shortcuts to "printer", "display devices" and "system control panel " in the panel?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, session

I would like to configure Unity session indicator in 12.10 like it was before in version 12.04.

Because I miss the practical shortcuts to "printer", "display devices" and "system control panel " in the menu.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't configure the session indicator in 12.10 to include that items.